# How to find the normal vector of a plane performing rotations about two axes?

Tags: vectors

I have a surface in $3$D  space undergoing two rotations. One about the $x$ axis and the other about the $z$ axis. If I want the unit normal to this surface in $3$D space, can I simply add the unit normals of each independent rotation together as shown in the attached picture? [plane rotations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3372.jpg)

**Unit normals:**

```
n1 = [0.0; cos(theta); sin(theta)]

n2 = [sin(gamma); cos(gamma); 0.0]
```

**Combined unit normal?:**

```
n_combined = [sin(gamma); cos(theta + gamma); sin(theta)]
```

Comment: No. The easiest way to see this is that changing the order of rotations will change the orientation of the normal vector while adding them will provide the same vector regardless of which rotation you do first.